# Строковые функции Left

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица `employees` :

```
| ID | FullName          | 
+----+-------------------+
| 1  | Юрий Сергеев      | 
| 2  | Юлия Демина       | 
| 3  | Людмила Якубова   |
| 4  | Смирнов Юсуф      |
| 5  | Ким Юлия          |
```

И запрос:

```
declare
@Agent nvarchar(200) = 'ю'
select ID, fullname From (
select 0 as ID, 'Bсе' as fullname
union
select 
e.ID, e.fullname
from employees e
Where 
(left(e.fullname,1) Like  '%' + @Agent + '%')) q
order by fullname
```

Результат запроса:

```
    | ID | FullName       | 
    +----+----------------+
    | 1  | Все            | 
    | 2  | Юлия Демина    | 
    | 3  | Юрий Сергеев   |
```

Как написать запрос чтобы результат был таким:

```
    | ID | FullName       | 
    +----+----------------+
    | 1  | Все            | 
    | 2  | Юлия Демина    | 
    | 3  | Юрий Сергеев   |  
    | 4  | Смирнов Юсуф   |
    | 5  | Ким Юлия       |  
    | 6  | Людмила Якубова|
```

То есть 1-м будет отображаться ФИО у которых первая буква 'Ю', 2-м имя начинающая на Ю а потом like по ФИО

Comment: Поясните, по какой логике строчка исходной таблицы `| 3  | Людмила Якубова   |` должна превратиться в `| 6  | Людмила Якубова   |`?

Comment: @Zhandos, что значит 1-ым будет отображаться? Вы же потом всё равно сортируете по fullname в запросе. Сформулируйтк точнее что вам надо, пока вообще не понятно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно отфильтровать по содержанию подстроки @Agent, затем отсортировать в порядке:

```
-первое слово начинается на @Agent 
-второе(вернее какое-то) слово начинается на @Agent 
-все остальные
```

Тогда делаем ORDER By + CASE

Про ORDER BY + CASE можно почитать тут: [sql-tutorial case + order by](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html)

```
declare
@Agent nvarchar(200) = 'ю'
select ID, fullname 
From (
  select 0 as ID, 'Bсе' as fullname
  union
  select 
  e.ID, e.fullname
  from employees e
  --фильтруем
  Where e.fulname Like  '%' + @Agent + '%' 
) q
order by
  CASE
    WHEN ID=0 THEN 0 --сначала выводим строку 'Все'
    WHEN fulname LIKE @Agent + '%' THEN 1 --начинается на @Agent   
    WHEN fulname LIKE '% ' + @Agent + '%' THEN 2 --какое-то слово начинается на @Agent 
    ElSE 3 -- все остальные
  END,  
  --ну и добавляем сортировку по fullname
  fullname
```

Получается сортировка по релевантности:)

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой запрос у меня получился:

```
SELECT 0 as ID, 'Bсе' AS FullName
UNION
SELECT ID, FullName FROM `employees` WHERE FullName LIKE 'ю%'
UNION
SELECT ID, FullName FROM `employees` WHERE FullName LIKE '% ю%'
UNION
SELECT ID, FullName FROM `employees` WHERE FullName LIKE '%ю%'
```

Результат:

```
ID  FullName    
0   Bсе
1   Юрий Сергеев
4   Юлия Демина
3   Смирнов Юсуф
5   Ким Юлия
2   Людмила Якубова
```

Исходная таблица:

```
ID  FullName
1   Юрий Сергеев
2   Людмила Якубова
3   Смирнов Юсуф
4   Юлия Демина
5   Ким Юлия
6   Иванов Иван
```

Comment: UNION уже устраняет дубликаты, DISTINCT лишний.

Comment: @pegoopik спасибо. до сих пор каждый раз что-то новое узнаю

Comment: зачем вы три раза обращаетесь к employees? Ваш запрос не эффективен. Кроме того UNION ваш запрос пересортирует, потому как устраняет дубликаты. Чем вам мой вариант в одно чтение не понравился?

Comment: Почему у вас в рузультат не попала Людмила Якубова? Ведь в имени есть буква 'ю'. И повторюсь, не надо три раза обращаться к таблице, потом делать UNION. Сортировку надо задавать ***явно***!

Comment: @pegoopik при копировании Людмила самоуволилась.
CASE до этого момента был мне не известен

Comment: Ой, я вас с автором перепутал:) Про "чем вам мой вариант не понравился" - это было не вам. Почему-то не даёт отредактировать.

Comment: @pegoopik посоветуйте путёвую статейку по теме использования CASE в ORDER BY

Comment: С радостью:)  http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html  А вообще там есть неплохая статья отдельно про CASE. Но самое главное - это конечно задачи.